# Handshake error when trying to connect to websocket using socket.io c++ library

Tags: c++, websocket, socket.io, handshake

I am trying to connect to websocket using socket.io c++ library:

```
    sio::client h;
    h.connect("ws://echo.websocket.org");

    Again:
    h.socket()->on("connect", [&](sio::event& ev)
    {
        HIGHLIGHT("TEST");
    });

    h.socket()->on("message", [&](sio::event& ev)
    {
        HIGHLIGHT("TEST");
    });

    goto Again;
```

Not sure if I am doing it correctly, I just found some similar example, and tried to make basic example to work, but I am getting following error:

```
***2017-12-20 03:50:53] [devel] endpoint constructor
[2017-12-20 03:50:53] [devel] client constructor
[2017-12-20 03:50:53] [connect] Successful connection
[2017-12-20 03:50:53] [error] Server handshake response error: websocketpp.processor:20 (Invalid HTTP status.)
Connection failed.
Reconnect for attempt:0***
```

Couldn't find any solution or workaround for this, and even some working example would be great.

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: I think not, because I would post solution for sure :)
I think we didn't needed it at the end at all